# Unproject mouse to get 3D world coordinates Libgdx

Tags: java, 3d, libgdx

**My Question:** How does one get a 3D model to move with the mouse cursor keeping the y location of the model at 0. (Using Libgdx)

**What I have tried:**
I'm trying to get my 3D models to follow my cursor.

At the moment I have simply made the models move with the x and y coordinates of my mouse with adding factors like a multiplier and camera location. This is not very good because it doesn't follow the cursor and if I rotate the camera then the model doesn't move in the correct direction.

This is the code I created for moving the model :

`instances.get(modelIndex).transform.setToTranslation(((Gdx.input.getX()-650)/10) + cam.position.x,0,((Gdx.input.getY()-400)/10)+ cam.position.z);`

Here's a link to an image of the problem (The green circle is where the mouse is).

[image: libgx mouse]

I know that I'm going about this wrong and that I should be using the unproject method. I have tried to use the unproject method and did have little success, the model was just stuck to the near pane of the camera. I want my object to stay at 0 on the y axes so I used this:

```
cam.unproject(mousePos);
instances.get(modelIndex).transform.setToTranslation(mousePos.x, 0, mousePos.z);
```

This then resulted in the model moving quite slowly(not with the mouse), in the right direction. Also when I rotated or moved the camera the model would be set somewhere in the distance or even behind the camera.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot simply use `camera.unproject`, because a single 2D coordinate can represent multiple coordinates in 3D space. Instead you can use `camera.getPickRay` to get the `Ray`, which is defined by the origin (the location on the camera's near plane) along with a direction into 3D space. So, you'll get the line in 3D space that represents the 2D coordinate:

```
Ray ray = cam.getPickRay(screenX, screenY);
```

Now you want the point (distance from origin) on that line (ray) where y=0:

```
ray.origin.y + ray.direction.y * distance = 0 <=>
ray.direction.y * distance = -ray.origin.y <=>
distance = -ray.origin.y / ray.direction.y
```

Resulting in:

```
float distance = -ray.origin.y / ray.direction.y;
```

Now to get the position on the ray at that distance:

```
Vector3 tmpVector = new Vector3();
tmpVector.set(ray.direction).scl(distance).add(ray.origin);
```

To set the model instance translation to that value you can use:

```
instance.transform.setTranslation(tmpVector);
```

Here `instance` is referring to your `instances.get(modelIndex)`.

I would encourage you to use InputProcessor (see http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/InputEvent), so to put it all together:

```
Vector3 tmpVector = new Vector3();
@Override
public boolean touchDragged (int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
    Ray ray = cam.getPickRay(screenX, screenY);
    final float distance = -ray.origin.y / ray.direction.y;
    tmpVector.set(ray.direction).scl(distance).add(ray.origin);
    instance.transform.setTranslation(tmpVector);
    return true;
}
```

Note that you might need to override `touchdown` and return `true` for `touchDragged` to be called.