# Dragging an object around (libgdx)

Tags: libgdx

Question: How do you drag an object in a 3d environment with libgdx?

I manage to pick the object by using a Ray projected from the screen point that I touch and checking if intersects the object's bounding box but I don't understand how to actually update its position. What I'm trying to achieve is a movement on the xz plane, so that when I drag my finger towards the upper ( or lower)  end of the screen, the objects move in depth on the plane. Anybody can help?

Comment: The answer to this perhaps similar question might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552284/unproject-mouse-to-get-3d-world-coordinates-libgdx/18552800#18552800